# Confirm message on removeOnspill event in angular dragula

Tags: angularjs, dragula

I would like to show a confirm  dialog  when i am draging an element out of the  bag (I am using angular and angular-dragula) . If I click ok, I want to delete the item, but if I click NO, i would like the element to come back to the place it was.

Thanku.

Comment: Have you got the solution for it. I am also in search of a solution for this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for the way of confirm. 
I tried it with window.confirm(), ugly, synchronous.
but it isn't good answer.

```
    revertOnSpill: true        

    .on('cancel',
    function(el, container, source) {
        if (confirm('delete?'))
            drake.remove(true);
    }
```